# Unable to find an element with React testing library testing a ternary operator

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-testing-library

In my React component `<MyBlock />` I have the following conditional rendering:

So when `variant="one"` prop is passed it will return `<Container />` component, when `variant="two"` is passed it will render  `<Scroller />`.

```
{variant === 'one' ? (
 <Container items={items} testId="container" />
 ) : (
 <Scroller items={items} testId="scroller" />
)}
```

With [React testing library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/) I am testing this component:

```
it('should render the container correctly', () => {
    const { getByTestId } = mount(<MyBlock data={MockData} variant="one" />);
    expect(getByTestId('container')).toBeDefined();
  });
```

This test pass and works fine.

Now I want to test the other `variant`:

```
  it('should render the container correctly', () => {
    const { getByTestId } = mount(<MyBlock data={MockData} variant="two" />);
    expect(getByTestId('scroller')).toBeDefined();
  });
```

But then I get:

> Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="scroller"]

What's the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. I have to use `queryByTestId` instead of `getByTestId`:

it('should render the container correctly', () => {
const { queryByTestId } = mount();
expect(queryByTestId('scroller')).toBeDefined();
});

Now it's working fine for both.